# the file 'info.plist' could not be opened because there is no such file

Tags: xcode, info.plist

I tried to deploy the app to the iphone device for test.When I pressed the run button, one error accured.pic is attched below.

"the file 'Simple-Info.plist' could not be opened because there is no such file".But the file is there in the project!

I mentioned the path of the file which was marked in red in the pic.Why there is 2 Simple(the Project name) in the path?

Anyone could help?!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode isn't a direct representation of what files are present in the folder. It shows what files are associated with the project. Go to your actual folder for the project and you will probably find that the file is missing. If you haven't emptied your trash, it could be there. It could have also been accidentally moved in which case you can search for it.

Comment: thank you for your comments.It was really missing in the actual folder.Now it's fixed.